# What is the OST at episode 156 of Naruto Shippuden at 4 minute mark?

Tags: naruto, music

What is the music in *Naruto Shippuden* episode 156, "Surpassing the Masters", at the 4 minute mark? I've also heard it at the end of episode 151. It has a bit of banjo and violin.

Answer (score 2):

This is an unreleased track. I found [a version of it on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-ibP_V6p-U) titled "Peaceful", but it's incomplete and has sound effects in it. There might be other versions online, but I didn't find any others in a cursory search.

(To make things more confusing, there are at least a couple of other unreleased tracks that have been given names like "Peaceful" and "Peace" and "Peaceful theme" too...)

Comment: thank you so much for the link i truly apreaciate it . have been looking for this for a long time =)